# Time range inputs in pine

Tags: pine-script

I just started learning pine on trading view. I have a basic strategy i want to test during specific trading hours.  How do i code a time range with adjustable inputs so i can change the hours my strategy will run?

I have followed a few tutorials and I can get the inputs but cant seem to get it to integrate with my strategy. I have been getting an unidentified identifier error with some of the attempts I have made. I must be missing a step.

This is the current code that has at least placed a time range in my input box but its not integrated into the strategy.
sessionHours = input(defval = "0700-1000", type = session, title="Session Hours")

I also tried a code that had the start time and end time as separate codes but couldn't get that to work.

Here are the inputs i have so far:

```
needlong = input(true, defval = true, title = "Long")
needshort = input(true, defval = true, title = "Short")
takepercent = input(0, defval = 0, minval = 0, maxval = 1000, title = 
"take, %")
needbe = input(true, defval = true, title = "Bands Entry")
needct = input(false, defval = false, title = "Counter-trend entry")
bodylen = input(10, defval = 10, minval = 0, maxval = 50, title = "Body 
length")
trb = input(1, defval = 1, minval = 1, maxval = 5, title = "Trend bars")
len = input(20, defval = 20, minval = 2, maxval = 200, title = "Period")
needbb = input(true, defval = true, title = "Show Bands")
needbg = input(true, defval = true, title = "Show Background")
fromyear = input(1900, defval = 1900, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title 
= "From Year")
toyear = input(2100, defval = 2100, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = 
"To Year")
frommonth = input(01, defval = 01, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "From 
Month")
tomonth = input(12, defval = 12, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "To 
Month")
sessionHours = input(defval = "0700-1000", type = session, title="Session 
Hours")
src = close
```

Here is the strategy code that i am trying to integrate the time range into:

```
if up7 == 1 or up8 == 1
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, needlong == false ? 0 : trend == -1 
and needct == false ? 0 : na, when=(time > timestamp(fromyear, frommonth, 
01, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(toyear, tomonth, 31, 00, 00)))

if dn7 == 1 or dn8 == 1
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, needshort == false ? 0 : trend == 
1 and needct == false ? 0 : na, when=(time > timestamp(fromyear, from 
month, 01, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(toyear, tomonth, 31, 00, 00)))

if time > timestamp(toyear, tomonth, 31, 00, 00)
strategy.close_all()
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Also provide the code and expected output vs what you got. (errors etc?). there are plenty of example code on TV so look at those scripts and in their wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to Pine Script, so there may be a better way.

Though I have not "variable-ized" my time frame inputs, I did get my strategy to trade only during certain hours of the trading day, using the time() function -- see https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_time .  Here is my bit of code that does this:

timeOKToBuy = na(time(timeframe.period, "0000-1000,1200-0000"))

Then condition your action (e.g. in my case, entry) on that variable.
The time() function returns a time if it is within one of the periods in the comma-separated list of ranges.  If it is not in such a range, it returns NaN, so when na() is called on its value, the result is true if the time of day is not in one of those ranges.  In my case, I wanted to allow a trade entry only from 10-12 Eastern time, so I listed the ranges outside that tradable range.

I don't yet know enough about Pine Script to understand how you'd get input for the time range, but I have seen examples and think it should be pretty easy.

I also don't know how time zones apply here ... but I'd guess TradingView has good doc on how to configure and work with time zones or time in its various formats.

Comment: Thanks i will give that a try, even without the input option i could still easily modify the time in the script.

Comment: Ok, i was able to try it and i got this "line 25: Undeclared identifier `timeframe.period`"  I have recieved these notices before when i have tried other codes and not sure whats going on,